# Trying to calculate monthly income with month-end issues

Tags: php, date, datetime, calculation, strtotime

I am trying to calculate monthly income but I want it to be automatic and I also want it to account for month-end issues..

I want it to calculate from/on the 12th to the 11th, but I want it to also include any income that came in on the 11th so that the 11th doesnt get left out each month..

I can get it to calculate, but its only calculating the income from/on the 12th to the 10th instead of the 11th.

I'm trying to make it automatic so that when the month changes it will still be accurate regardless of whether the month has 28, 30 or 31 days but I cannot find a way of doing it correctly where it accounts for all these things.

I'm doing this for 3 months, so 3 pieces of code underneath one another, but it seems that only the second block of code (which would be calculating the 12th, May - 11th, June) is not including the income for the 11th (although this could be the same for the current month too, I wont know until next month),

EDIT - Its only a simple gross profit too, so its only multiplying the 'price' column by the 'quantity' column foreach row then summing up the total.

**EDIT - I manually calculated gross profit from the 3rd month back too (April 12th - 11th May), but its accurate since there was no income on the 11th of May, so I believe the only issue is with it not including any income on the 11th each month**

this is what I have:

Any help will be really appreciated!

**Current Month:**

```
<h5 style="color:black;">Monthly Earnings <small style="font-size:12px;">(gross profit)</small></h5>

    <br>

    <?php
// Set the timezone to the appropriate timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

// Get the current date
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');

// Determine the start and end dates for the current period
$current_month = date('n', strtotime($current_date));
$current_year = date('Y', strtotime($current_date));

// Adjust the start date to be the 12th of the current month
$start_date_1st = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$current_year-$current_month-12"));

// Determine the number of days in the current month
$days_in_month = date('t', strtotime($current_date));

// Adjust the end date based on the number of days in the current month
if (date('j', strtotime($current_date)) < 12) {
// If the current date is before the 12th, set the end date to the 11th of the current month
$end_date_1st = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("11-$current_month-$current_year"));
} else {
// If the current date is on or after the 12th, set the end date to the 11th of the next month
if ($current_month == 12) {
    $next_month = 1;
    $next_year = $current_year + 1;
} else {
    $next_month = $current_month + 1;
    $next_year = $current_year;
}
$end_date_1st = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("11-$next_month-$next_year"));
}

// Format the start and end dates as "Month, day"
$start_date_formatted_1st = date('F, jS', strtotime($start_date_1st));
$end_date_formatted_1st = date('F, jS', strtotime($end_date_1st));
$today_formatted = date('F, jS', strtotime($current_date));

if ($today_formatted == $start_date_formatted_1st) {
    $start_date_formatted_1st = "Today";
}

// Query the database for orders within the current period
$howMuch = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `date` BETWEEN :start_date_1st AND :end_date_1st ORDER BY `id`");
$howMuch->bindParam(':start_date_1st', $start_date_1st);
$howMuch->bindParam(':end_date_1st', $end_date_1st);
$howMuch->execute();
$seeSold = $howMuch->fetchAll();

// Calculate the total profit for the current period
$Money1st = 0;
foreach ($seeSold as $firstResult) {
    $secondResult = $firstResult['price'] * $firstResult['quantity'];
    $Money1st += $secondResult;
}
?>

<h6 style="color:black;margin-top:0;"><?php echo $start_date_formatted_1st . ' - ' . $end_date_formatted_1st;?></h6>

<?php if (!empty($seeSold)):?>
<h3 style="color:black;">£<?php echo number_format(round($Money1st, 2), 2);?></h3>
<?php else: ?>
<h3 style="color:black;">£0.00</h3>
<?php endif ?>
```

**Previous Month:**

```
<?php
// Set the timezone to the appropriate timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

// Get the current date
$current_date = new DateTime();

// Determine the start and end dates for the previous period
$current_month = $current_date->format('n');
$current_year = $current_date->format('Y');

// Calculate the start and end dates for the previous period
if ($current_month == 1) {
    $start_date_2nd = new DateTime("12-12-" . ($current_year - 1));
    $end_date_2nd = new DateTime("11-$current_month-$current_year");
} else {
    $start_date_2nd = new DateTime("12-" . ($current_month - 1) . "-$current_year");
    $end_date_2nd = new DateTime("11-$current_month-$current_year");
}

// Format the start and end dates as "F jS"
$start_date_formatted_2nd = $start_date_2nd->format('F jS');
$end_date_formatted_2nd = $end_date_2nd->format('F jS');

// Query the database for orders within the previous period
$howMuchSecond = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `date` BETWEEN :start_date_2nd AND :end_date_2nd ORDER BY `id`");
$howMuchSecond->bindParam(':start_date_2nd', $start_date_2nd->format('Y-m-d'));
$howMuchSecond->bindParam(':end_date_2nd', $end_date_2nd->format('Y-m-d'));
$howMuchSecond->execute();
$secondMonthAmount = $howMuchSecond->fetchAll();

// Calculate the total profit for the previous period
$moneyStart = 0;
foreach ($secondMonthAmount as $secondMonthResult) {
    $secondPartResult = $secondMonthResult['price'] * $secondMonthResult['quantity'];
    $moneyStart += $secondPartResult;
}
?>

<h6 style="color:black;margin-top:0;"><?php echo $start_date_formatted_2nd . ' - ' . $end_date_formatted_2nd;?></h6>

<?php if ($moneyStart > 0):?>
<h3 style="color:black;">£<?php echo number_format(round($moneyStart, 2), 2);?></h3>
<?php else: ?>
<h3 style="color:black;">£0.00</h3>
<?php endif ?>
```

**3rd Month Back:**

```
<?php
// Set the timezone to the appropriate timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

// Get the current date
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');

// Determine the start and end dates for the previous period
$current_month = date('n', strtotime($current_date));
$current_year = date('Y', strtotime($current_date));
if (date('d', strtotime($current_date)) <= 11) {
    $start_date_3rd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("12-$current_month-$current_year -3 months"));
    $end_date_3rd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("11-$current_month-$current_year -2 months"));
} else {
    $start_date_3rd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("12-$current_month-$current_year -2 months"));
    $end_date_3rd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("11-$current_month-$current_year -1 month"));
}

// Format the start and end dates as "Month, day"
$start_date_formatted_3rd = date('F, jS', strtotime($start_date_3rd));
$end_date_formatted_3rd = date('F, jS', strtotime($end_date_3rd));

// Query the database for orders within the previous period
$month3rdback = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `date` BETWEEN :start_date_3rd AND :end_date_3rd ORDER BY `id`");
$month3rdback->bindParam(':start_date_3rd', $start_date_3rd);
$month3rdback->bindParam(':end_date_3rd', $end_date_3rd);
$month3rdback->execute();
$see3rdMonth = $month3rdback->fetchAll();

// Calculate the total profit for the previous period
$readySet = 0;
foreach ($see3rdMonth as $month3rdbackResult) {
    $month3rdbackSecondRes = $month3rdbackResult['price'] * $month3rdbackResult['quantity'];
    $readySet += $month3rdbackSecondRes;
}
?>

<h6 style="color:black;margin-top:0;"><?php echo $start_date_formatted_3rd . ' - ' . $end_date_formatted_3rd;?></h6>

<?php if (!empty($see3rdMonth)): ?>
<h3 style="color:black;">£<?php echo number_format(round($readySet, 2), 2);?></h3>
<?php else: ?>
<h3 style="color:black;">£0.00</h3>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: `I'm doing this for 3 months, so 3 pieces of code underneath one another`...why? Unless the logic is different in each case for some reason, one function with appropriate input parameters ought to be able to handle any time period you give to it. Duplicating your code is never a good idea.

Comment: If you are processing data in the range `12th to the 11th,` then the number of days in a month becomes irrelevant, surely

Comment: @ADyson because on the same page I also have other calculations for other things such as stock count, yearly income, net profit and some others, the variables are unique for all and everything else is functioning perfectly, its just this monthly thing thats having issues, it just wont include income from the 11th.

Comment: That's not a reason for having 3 separate calculation blocks all for doing the same thing (i.e. calculating a monthly total).

Comment: Anyway it looks like it sets the date range correctly: https://3v4l.org/h1HbU . And BETWEEN in mysql is inclusive, but you are advised to cast the string to DATE before comparing (see https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between). Have you tried that? It may not be necessary due to your parameterisation, but worth a try. It's difficult to see what else could be causing it. If you run the query manually in SQL with strings for the dates, do you get the expected rows back?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah thats what I thought but it doesnt seem to work like that because I had it calculate as a month before and it just does it as 30 days regardless of month.

Comment: Can you provide an anonymised example of what a record looks like? Is the `date` field of type `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`? If so your query will be checking for orders before and on `2023-01-11 00:00:00`, meaning nothing that occurs that day

Comment: @ADyson Yeah I know I shouldnt have seperate blocks its mainly for testing and working out issues. Yes the date range was displaying correctly just not the income, but I have changed my query and added `CAST` as suggested and it is now calculating accurately, thankyou for your help! I think I need to look more into this `CAST` because I believe I've only actually used it once before for something else, I didnt realise the difference it would make to the accuracy of the calculation, thanks again!

Comment: It just ensures that the date value is treated as a date type, and not anything else. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I know you solved it out by `CAST`ing, but I figured I would put this solution in here as you can replace your PHP code to find the sum with a SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(id) as number_of_orders, 
    ROUND(SUM(price * quantity),2) as gross_profit 
FROM orders 
    WHERE date BETWEEN CAST(:start) AND CAST(:end);
```

Then chuck that in a function for re-usability:

```
function getGrossProfit($dbh, $startDate, $endDate)
{
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) as number_of_orders, ROUND(SUM(price * quantity),2) as gross_profit FROM orders WHERE date BETWEEN CAST(:start) AND CAST(:end)");
    $query->bindParam(':start', $startDate);
    $query->bindParam(':end', $endDate);
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, yeah that is definitely a lot simpler way of doing it, thanks!